# Since the pressure's greater on the bottom of you than the top, shouldn't there be a force acting upward on you?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, free-body-diagram, buoyancy

Suppose there's an upright cylinder in the water. The pressure at the bottom's more then the pressure at the top, so shouldn't there be a net force upwards? Does this matter much?

Comment: Yes, there is. See buoyant force and Archimedes' principle.

Comment: It matters a lot for boats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a net upwards force from the fluid. It is called the [buoyant force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy).

Comment: ohh... that makes sense. so the buoyant force doesn't exist, just the pressure difference which pushes it up. thanks a bunch :)